# Here I have mostly white and yellow Legos bu need the set they go to

Tags: set-identification

Here I have mostly white and yellow Legos bu need the set they go to.
Can you help identify the set?[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Pearl Gold Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Vertical in pearl gold](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15070) plus [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 3 Teeth in white](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15208) plus [Slope, Curved 6 x 1 Inverted in bright light orange](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42023) (not yellow!) means [41179-1 Queen Dragon's Rescue](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41179-1).